# Getting ReferenceError: readFile is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am currently learning node js
and I am getting

ReferenceError: readFile is not defined

after typing node . in the terminal

here is the code

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  readFile("./home.html", "utf8", (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
      response.status(500).send("sorry, out of order");
    }

    response.send(html);
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () =>
  console.log("http://localhost:3000")
);
```

Comment: have you imported fs module

Comment: how can I import the fs module

Comment: const fs = require('fs') and then fs.readFile

Comment: The video I am following don't import the fs module.but the code you send works thanks

Comment: In general, you can refer this in future: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import file system module:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// ...

fs.readFile('...')
```

Comment: const { readFile } = require("fs"); also works

Comment: @Shanxx Exactly, that is another way to import a single function instead of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJS if you want to do operation(Read, Write etc.) on files you have to use file system module provided by nodeJS.
Before using this module you have to import(ES6) or require it.
You can take reference from below how to use file system in node js

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('Demo.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
  
// Display the file content
console.log(data);
});
```